# Next month in named list

Tags: excel

I have a named range `PostingDate`. It has dates that are every Friday (ie. Jan 10, 2020; Jan 17, 2020; Jan 24, 2020 etc.). There could be multiples of any of the Friday's.

In `C2`, I put `=MIN(PostingDate)` and then format as `mmm yyyy`. In the cell to the right, I want the following month, if it exists in the named range. I tried putting `=IF(DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2)+1,DAY(*)=PostingDate,EDATE(C2,1),""`. I put the * because I want to say **any day of the month**. This doesn't work I guess because the wildcard isn't correctly being used. Basically, I am trying to figure out how to look for something using an `IF` statement in a named range.

[image]

So in `C2` I have `=MIN(PostingDate)` which inputs Dec 6, 2019 and I format to `mmm yyyy`. In `D2` I have `=EDATE(C2,1)` which puts Jan 2020. If I continue to drag the function to the right, I will get Feb 2020 and Mar 2020 and so on. I don't want the other months because they don't exist in my data (but they will eventually as time goes on so then I'd want them to show up). So I want only the months that are in my named range, and with the errors I will use `=IFERROR` to clean up.

Comment: Can you share some sample data here? Then show some expected inputs and outputs given the sample data

Answer (score 2):

**If** you have access to the new excel equations you can use `UNIQUE` to create a spill over range containing all combinations of unique months & year in your range

```
=TEXT(UNIQUE(MONTH(A1:A20)&"-"&YEAR(A1:A20)),"MMM YYYY")

'Where A1:A20 is the range of all dates
```

---

Details about the `Unique` function can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e)